# OpenID Connect with Angular 4.3

Tags: angular, typescript, openid-connect

I've decided to use [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/blob/master/README.md) project to get the job done, but right after installing the package and doing the imports, in console I've got

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for Router!

I already have Router imported in the app.module, though I am going to use OpenID in another component called auth.component, which has only 'header' stuff now.

Here's my **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Import HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SearchComponent } from '../search/search.component';
import { AuthComponent } from '../auth/auth.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
// OpenID Connect
import { AuthModule, OidcSecurityService, OpenIDImplicitFlowConfiguration } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    AuthComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [OidcSecurityService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {  constructor(public oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) {

          let openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration = new OpenIDImplicitFlowConfiguration();
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.stsServer = 'https://localhost:4200';
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.redirect_url = 'https://localhost:4200';
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.client_id = 'angularclient';
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.response_type = 'id_token token';
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.scope = 'openid email profile';
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.post_logout_redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:4200/Unauthorized';
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.start_checksession = false;
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.silent_renew = true;
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.silent_renew_offset_in_seconds = 0;
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.startup_route = '/home';
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.forbidden_route = '/Forbidden';
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.unauthorized_route = '/Unauthorized';
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.auto_userinfo = true;
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.log_console_warning_active = true;
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.log_console_debug_active = false;
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds = 10;
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.override_well_known_configuration = false;
          openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.override_well_known_configuration_url = 'https://localhost:4200/wellknownconfiguration.json';
          // openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.storage = localStorage;

          this.oidcSecurityService.setupModule(openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration);
      }}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

I am also open to any new suggestions to solve my authentication problem, I don't have preferences, what I need is an easy way to authenticate users with:
**Google, Mail.ru, Facebook and Vk.com**

By the way, my backend is written on PHP (Lumen)

Comment: find any workaround?

Comment: @gog no, I ended up creating a php identification server using lumen with socialiteproviders